# Parsing a string to get last name in Swift

Tags: swift, string, substring

I'm writing a app where I need to present the second name of a person on the screen.

The names are always "firstname space lastname" as in:

```
let str = "Fred Bloggs"

let secondStr = "William Wright"
```

Can you tell me how to get "Bloggs" out of that first string and "Wright" out of the second string, not knowing the index of Bloggs. All the examples I've seen seem to assume you know the index of the position you want to get a substring from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

let fullName    = "First Last"
let fullNameArr = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")

let name    = fullNameArr[0]
let lastName = fullNameArr[1]
```